# Attribute usage MSDN guildelines clarification

Tags: c#, custom-attributes, msdn

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out the meaning of this advice from [Attribute Usage Guildelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/2ab31zeh#Y195):

> Do not define a parameter with both named and positional arguments. The following code example illustrates this pattern.

And the code is:

```
public class NameAttribute: Attribute 
{
   string userName;
   int age;

   // This is a positional argument.
   public NameAttribute (string userName) 
   { 
       this.userName = userName;
   }
   public string UserName 
   { 
      get 
      {
         return userName; 
      }
   }
   // This is a named argument.
   public int Age 
   { 
      get 
      {
         return age;
      }
      set 
      {
         age = value;
      }
   } 
}
```

Now, I'm sorry if it's really simple and I am wasting your time. But I just don't understand the meaning and what example demonstrates. The fact that English is not my native language might be a factor, but I didn't experience any difficulties reading MSDN before. I also tried to read the translated version of this article, but it makes even less sense to me.

So, if someone would be kind enough to rephrase and explain it to me, that would be really helpful. If you can also explain why MSDN advises to do so, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are the victim of a crummy example, it doesn't actually demonstrate the problem.  A better example of doing it wrong is adding this constructor:

```
public NameAttribute (string userName, int age) 
{ 
    this.userName = userName;
    this.Age = age;
}
```

Now the client code could use the attribute this way:

```
[Name("foo", 42)]
```

*and* this way:

```
[Name("foo", Age = 42)]
```

Both are equally valid, the client programmer won't be able to make up his mind which one to choose.  A much nastier example would be this constructor:

```
public NameAttribute(int age) {
    this.userName = "unspecified";
    this.Age = age;
}
```

which allows:

```
[Name(42, Age = 43)]
```

Comment: Yes, if that's the case, I do see the point. Thanks, I think that's it. The example on another language wouldn't event compile so I think it's possible that it is also wrong in general.

Answer (score 4):

Think about how you would have to use such an attribute:

```
[Name("Jack", Age = 25)]
public class ClassToDecorate { }
```

Now, this doesn't look all that clear because two styles are being mixed: `UserName` is being set via the attribute's constructor ("positional"), but `Age` is being explicitly set as a property ("named").

The guideline is suggesting that it would be better to redesign the attribute such that *exactly* one of the following decorations would work:

```
[Name("Jack", 25)] // Positional only
```

(or)

```
[Name(UserName = "Jack", Age = 25)] // Named only
```

Comment: But such attributes are all over the place in BCL, like `AttributeUsage` and many others

Comment: A lot of the Framework Design Guidelines are from experiences the .NET team had over the years - they didn't get everything right on the first try (but are stuck with the APIs now), so the guidelines aren't meant to say what the framework does.  Rather, they're what the framework would have done, had they known then what they know now.

Comment: @Austin Lamb: yeah, I know, but using of `AttributeUsage` like that in the same guideline is kinda messed up.

Comment: Also, I don't understand what "a parameter" refers to in this example

Comment: @Dyppl - I believe "a parameter" is referring to not creating a property that can be set with a constructor *and* by a property setter. Use one or the other.

Comment: @Metro Smurf: but the article says that example demonstrates this pattern. This example clearly doesn't, `UserName` has no setter.

Comment: @Dyppl: The example is demonstrating the *not* -recommended pattern, i.e. mixing the 2 styles. In the example, `UserName` *must* be set "positionally" (the property does not have a setter), and `Age` *must* be set in a "named" manner (the constructor does not accept a parameter for it).

Comment: @Dyppl - You're right. That is confusing. The example is demonstrating the pattern of using a constructor for one property and a property setter for a different property. This is what @Ani's answer clarifies. So, perhaps "a parameter" should say "an attribute"?